# How do I get string from metadata, not int

Tags: android

For example here is a meta-data in manifest file:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="AppId"
        android:value="347" />
```

Here is my code:

```
Activity instance = getActivity();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = instance.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(instance.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
if (appInfo.metaData != null) 
    result = appInfo.metaData.getString(key);
```

I find that "result" is null! why? Can it keep "AppId" as string for me?

Comment: Can you show us more code, like what is "key" being set to? Perhaps the whole fragment you have this code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that the applicationInfo.metaData is Bundle
Maybe you can use this method I wrote.

```
@Nullable
public static String getAppMetaData(Context ctx, String key) {
    if (ctx == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(key)) {
        return null;
    }
    String resultData = null;
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = ctx.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager != null) {
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            if (applicationInfo != null) {
                if (applicationInfo.metaData != null) {
                    resultData = String.valueOf(applicationInfo.metaData.get(key));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultData;
}
```

no matter the value is String or int

Comment: It doesn't work.
"2882303761517553085" became "2.88230376E18"

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this.

```
Activity instance = getActivity();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = instance.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(instance.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            if (appInfo.metaData != null) 
                result = String.valueOf(appInfo.metaData.getInt(key));
```